# Right fork mounting point

Tags: fork, front, led-lights

I was given an old racer frame and some parts which I am converting into a single speed commuter.

The front right fork has a small toothed mounting point, it looks a bit like it could have held a light or similar in a past life.

Can anyone shed some light `pardon the pun` on what exactly this mount point is and what it was used for.

[image: Front fork mounting point]
[image: Closeup]

Also are there any potential modern day applications for this mount point, does anyone sell any LEDs or adapters that make use of this interesting little feature.

Comment: Yeah, probably for a light.  Which would suggest that the bike started life as a tourer.

Comment: Headlight is the only thing that makes sense. The little teeth are probably to keep the light from turning once the bolt is tightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell from the photo whether a light or something else was mounted there in the past. It's certainly possible.

There aren't any modern lights I'm aware of designed specifically to mount to the side of the fork like that. Many dynamo hub lights are designed to mount to the joint of the left/right sides (i.e. the crown) of the fork, but that type of mount wouldn't fit well on the side.

It would be fairly easy to take a small piece of plastic or metal tubing and an appropriately sized screw, and create a small mount that a regular bike handlebar light mount could go on. For a step-by-step example, see [this blog post](http://problemsolversbike.com/blog/comments/free_diy_light_mount_via_urban_velo). Below is a picture of their final setup:

[image: bike light fork mount]

Comment: I thought of a dynamo too, but it seems to be a little too low to reach the tire .. I suppose that's why you mention attaching a piece of plastic, but I wonder if that was the original intention

Comment: http://www.commutebybike.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/front-mid-fork-mounting-eyelets-300x199.jpg

Comment: @gaurwraith I was also thinking it might have been a mounting point for a fender or rack, but it's only on one side, which makes that seem unlikely.

Comment: I've added a closeup.